# Explain how this command finds the 5 most CPU intensive processes

Tags: bash, shell

If I have the command

```
ps | sort -k 3,3 | tail -n 5
```

How is this find the 5 most CPU intensive processes?

I get that it is taking all the processes, sorting them based on a column through the -k option, but what does 3,3 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read what you seek for from the official manual of `sort` (`info sort` in linux); in particular, you are interested in the following extracts:

> ```
> ‘-k POS1[,POS2]’
> ‘--key=POS1[,POS2]’
>      Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between
>      POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted),
>      _inclusive_.
> ```

and, skipping a few paragraphs,

> ```
>  Example: To sort on the second field, use ‘--key=2,2’ (‘-k 2,2’).
>  See below for more notes on keys and more examples.  See also the
>  ‘--debug’ option to help determine the part of the line being used
>  in the sort.
> ```

So, basically, 3,3 emphasises that only the third column shall be considered for sorting, and the others will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much, makes complete sense! Will definitely be reading the official manual from now on